# how to create a method in service for http post in angular?

Tags: angularjs, http-post

i have

```
$http({
                url: 'http://webapi.-----UA_WebApi/GetUserAccount',
                method: 'POST',
                params: {Username:Username, Password:Password},
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
            })
```

and in my service  i wrote this method :

```
PostLogin: function (apiName, params) {
                var fullParams = getFullParams(apiName, params);
                var promise = $resource(buildUrl(apiName), {}, POST).get(fullParams).$promise;
                updateAllowedFilters(promise);
                return promise;
            }
```

if anyone could help me understand what i am doing (right and wrong) pls ?
i would also like an example in how to use the angular resource for post.
the `PostLogin` works

```
 PostLogin: function (apiName, params) {
                    var fullParams = getFullParams(apiName, params);
                    var promise = $resource(buildUrl(apiName), {}, POST).get(fullParams).$promise;
                    updateAllowedFilters(promise);
                    return promise;
                }
.then(function (results) {
                if(results.data.TotalRows==1) {}
```

TotalRows is undefined when debugging. but there is TotalRows in the api
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var actions = {
        post: {
            method: 'post',
            transformResponse: function(data) {
                // here is your chance to change received data 
                return new Model(angular.fromJson(data));
            }
        }
    };
var url = "http://postSomeData/:id/somethingElse/:name";
var parameters = { id : 1, name : "test" }
var data = { name : "test", type : "some type" };

return $resource(url, parameters, actions).post(data).$promise;
```

Comment: Model is user defined factory if you want to add capabilities to your received data like methods

Comment: 405 means method not allowed, what happens if you send OPTIONS to that url with postman or fiddler? does it say it is ok to POST?

Comment: i dont have much clue abou that but i have added  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' to the reportService.PostLogin. but i think that will take it as parameter

Comment: think that is a good thing to do but I get the feeling its all about what your url is allowing,I could be wrong

Comment: what does your backend consist of, java, node, .net?

Comment: if its .net mvc you put a [HttpPost] on the method, if its nodejs you can add a middleware to it to state which verbs are for a specifc resource

Comment: another question also,  var data = { name : "test", type : "some type" };

return $resource(url, parameters, actions).post(data).$promise; making data like that, it will only post 'test' ?

Comment: back end api is written in  .net mvc

Comment: I find things succeed more often on the .net side if the signature looks like [HttpPost] public void PostMethod(Data data){}   where data is a POCO containing the properties name,type

Comment: regarding your data question, you may have to do post(JSON.stringify(data))  , not sure